# Show sum of amounts of two types of status

Tags: mysql

I have a table transaction with columns amount and status.There are three kinds of status approved, void and cancelled. I want such a query which will out put as follows:

```
approved cancelled void 
$123     $144      $155
```

where $123, $144 and $155 are sum of the total amounts of each kind of transactions as defined by status.

Please help me.

Comment: Do you have a table or better explanation it kind of hard to know what you want

Comment: ok what I want is under approved column sum(amount) all approved transactions, under cancelled sum(amount) of all cancelled transactions and so on

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the application level. Otherwise, look at constructing a pivot query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a conditional expression inside of a aggregate, something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(t.status='approved' ,t.amount,0) AS approved 
     , SUM(IF(t.status='cancelled',t.amount,0) AS cancelled
     , SUM(IF(t.status='void'     ,t.amount,0) AS void
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE ...
```

**NOTE** The `IF()` function evaluates the first argument as a boolean; if the first argument evaluates as TRUE, the function returns the second argument, else it returns the third argument.

The `SUM()` is a standard aggregate function; in this example, it's just operating on an expression like it operates on any expression.

The `IF()` function is MySQL specific.  The ANSI standard equivalent:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN t.status='approved'  THEN t.amount ELSE 0 END) AS approved
     , SUM(CASE WHEN t.status='cancelled' THEN t.amount ELSE 0 END) AS cancelled
     , SUM(CASE WHEN t.status='void'      THEN t.amount ELSE 0 END) AS AS void
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE ...
```

Again, the `SUM()` aggregate is just operating on an expression, like it always does.

**FOLLOWUP**

**Q** What if there are other transactions with other kind of status but I want to display the sum of others status in one column?

**A** Again, just use an expression that evaluates to TRUE on every row you want the **amount** value returned for; sometimes it's more convenient to invert the test so that **amount** is returned for the else condition, rather than the then, e.g.

```
SELECT SUM(IF(t.status='approved' ,t.amount,0) AS approved 
     , SUM(IF(t.status='cancelled',t.amount,0) AS cancelled
     , SUM(IF(t.status='void'     ,t.amount,0) AS void
     , SUM(IF(t.status IN ('approved','cancelled','void'), 0, t.amount) AS others
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE ...
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you once again what if there are other transactions with other kind of status but I want to display the sum of others status in one column

Comment: you could use the same syntax to add another result column which is the sum of all rows where NOT t.status in ('approved', 'cancelled', 'void')